# Create dataTables in a Django application

Tags: javascript, python, django, datatable, datatables

I have followed [this tutorial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-datatables-view) in order to add **dataTables** module to my django project, but I don't know how am I suposed to actually create that table on my `mytable.html` page.

**models.py**:

```
from django.db import models

class SomeData(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

relevant part from **views.py**:

```
class OrderListJson(BaseDatatableView):
    model = SomeData
    columns = ['first_name', 'second_name']
    order_columns = ['first_name', 'second_name']
    max_display_length = 500

    def render_column(self, row, column):
        if column == 'user':
            return '{0} {1}'.format(row.customer_firstname, row.customer_lastname)
        else:
            return super(OrderListJson, self).render_column(row, column)

    def filter_queryset(self, qs):
        search = self.request.GET.get(u'search[value]', None)
        if search:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=search)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from proiect import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'demo/', views.demo_page),
    url(r'tabel/$', views.mytable_page, name='order_list_json'), # something may be wrong here but I am not sure
]
```

**mytable.html** (I don't know how to show the data in a table and how to actually print the table)

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>TablEs Demo</title>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.7/daterangepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.8/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>

<body>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.0.7/daterangepicker.js"></script>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
              <!--here I should have something to print the table and some data in it -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var oTable = $('.datatable').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "{% url 'order_list_json' %}"
      });
    });
    </script>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this with `here I should have something to print the table and some data in it`

```
<table class="datatable">
    <thead>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Second Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and `url(r'tabel/$', views.mytable_page, name='order_list_json')` with `url(r'tabel/$', views.OrderListJson.as_view(), name='order_list_json')`